# How to put an api into celery task in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery

I am using Django, celery, and DjangoRestFramework for APIs. 
I have an API that takes around 1 minute to show data in JSON format. The problem is Heroku ( server) shows application error if a function takes more than 30 seconds. Hence I want to put my API into celery tasks. 
Please suggest the way to do so.

Comment: Do you mean that you make a request to an end point then that end point does internal processing and then return you the dat ?

Comment: may be need try to refactor the code? did you try it?

Comment: @Umair I want the whole API inside the tasks file, rather than parts of API in the celery tasks.

Comment: Celery is mean to for `asynchronous` tasks whereas REST-API is mean to `synchronous`

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge, yes, you are right, but the problem is what should I do when an asynchronous task takes more than 30 seconds, Heroku server starts showing an application error. That why I thought of putting the whole API in celery async task.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can do something like this :

1. GET/POST/etc come to a particular end-point
2. View attached to url is activated
3. Here you can start/initialize the celery task and return the job id (investigation needed on this id part, I guess celery task return some EagerResult or something syncronously/ you can implement custom job id feature)
4. User gets the job id for there particular request

5 User can make another request after some delay using that id

6. If that celery tasks is completed then return result based on job id

This is just an overview of my initial thoughts. Much thoughts, refinement required.

Lemme know your thoughts.